# Is there a way to lock guides in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, guides

I have tried increasing the Snap distance, but even then, sometimes I accidentally move a guide when I'm trying to do a lot of repetitive tasks quickly.

Is there a way to lock guides in GIMP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't a way to lock the guides.  However when using the Move tool you can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when using the Move tool, so that the guide will not be able to be selected or moved accidentally.

This behaviour is documented in the user manual [here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html)

Answer (score 1):

Possible work around: instead of adding guides, create a Path (with vertical & horizontal lines) with the path tool, then check View>Snap to active path. The path ill behave as a guide, but you won't be able to move it by accident.

Comment: this is a very useful tip as well; unfortunately I can't accept two answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can mark, in move tool, the option to move the active layer, then the guides are blocked. I do this in Gimp 2.10.

Comment: Same as Bill Kerr's answer...